# React JS - Fullscreen background image with varying aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have a background image in svg and I want it to render it over the entire screen. I know this can be accomplished by setting the width and height to 100%.

```js
render() {
    let imgUrl = '/static/images/login_page.svg'
    let styles = {
      root: {
        backgroundSize: "stretch",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      }
    }

    return ( < div className = "contentview" >
        < div className = "test" >
        < img src = "/static/images/login_page.svg" style ={styles.root}/>
  </div >

        < /div>
  );
```

But when I do, the aspect ratio is kept intact, and almost half of the image is below the screen (as the image is almost squared). And this is no matter what I set height to. 150, 100 or 50, none seems to matter...

What do I have to set if I want to have 100% of the image cover 100% of the screen?

Comment: Does login_page.svg have a viewBox attribute? If so does it have preserveAspectRatio attribute too and what is it set to?

Comment: Nope, it does not. contain a viewBox attribute.

Comment: How about width and height attributes then? Are they set to 100%

Comment: Try backgroundPosition: center and backgroundSize: cover

Comment: Sorry, it generated the same behaviour: full width, missing bottom. An alternative, if you may, would be to position the image in the middle, if that is easier?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] then.